# Excluding aggregating project from SBT jar assembly production

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

How can one exclude an aggregating project that does nothing but aggregating subproject from producing a jar file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must disable the plugin for the aggregating project:

```
aggregatorProject.disablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
```

This will however disable the plugin for the aggregator and the aggregated projects.

You can enable the plugin for the aggregated projects by enabling them explicitly:

```
aggregatedProject.enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
```